# Crash during the function CryptEncrypt

Tags: c++, encryption, wincrypt

I'm writting little program that will generate RSA key pair, export\import keys and encrypt string.
So, I have written this code:

```
void EncryptString(std::string data) 
{
int lenght = strlen(data.c_str());
DWORD temp = data.length() * sizeof(char);
DWORD possiblersa = 0;

unsigned char* buffer = new unsigned char[lenght];

std::copy(data.begin(), data.end(), buffer);

if (!CryptEncrypt(hKey, NULL, true, NULL, NULL, &possiblersa, NULL))
{
    printf("Error: %d\n", GetLastError());
    ExitThread(0);
}

if (!CryptEncrypt(hKey, NULL, true, NULL, buffer, &temp, possiblersa)) // Problem here
{
    printf("Error: %d\n", GetLastError());
    ExitThread(0);
}

DWORD dlen = 0;
if (!CryptBinaryToString(buffer, possiblersa, CRYPT_STRING_BASE64, NULL, &dlen))
{
    printf("Error: %d\n", GetLastError());
    ExitThread(0);
}

TCHAR* str = new TCHAR[dlen];

if (!CryptBinaryToString(buffer, possiblersa, CRYPT_STRING_BASE64, str, &dlen))
{
    printf("Error: %d\n", GetLastError());
    ExitThread(0);
}

for (DWORD i = 0; i < dlen; i++) 
{
    printf("%d\n", str);
}

delete[] buffer;
delete[] str;
}
```

CryptEncrypt ends with the crash. I don't know what should I do to fix this issue.

Comment: `int lenght = strlen(data.c_str());` - it's spelled "length" and you can use `data.size()` or `data.length` - as, in fact, you do on the next line.

Comment: What happened when you examined your crash in the debugger? What crypto library are you using and what should the arguments be? What actually was the value of `possiblersa` in the crashing call? What is `hKey`?

Comment: It is very confusing to use `NULL` as an argument that expects a `DWORD`.  `NULL` really ought to be `nullptr` which is not a valid `DWORD` (but you are probably using a backwards compatibility mode where `NULL` is just zero).

Comment: but problem still exists

Comment: @Useless He's using the standard crypto library on Windows:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wincrypt/nf-wincrypt-cryptencrypt

Comment: Cheers!
OK, so once you fix your calls not to abuse NULL (and assuming you can't use the new API since this one is deprecated), what were the _values_ of the arguments passed to the failing call?

Comment: EncryptString("badumtssviuuuu");

Comment: @veter0 No.  That's the argument to `EncryptString`.  What were the arguments to the call to `CryptEncrypt` which failed.

Comment: @MartinBonner, `CryptEncrypt(hKey, NULL, true, NULL, buffer, &temp, possiblersa)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CryptEncrypt(hKey, NULL, true, NULL, NULL, &possiblersa, NULL))
```

will store in `possiblersa` the amount of data that will be returned by encrypting zero bytes from the null pointer.  You almost certainly need to pass in the actual data you want to encrypt (from `data.c_str()`).

```
CryptEncrypt(hKey, NULL, true, NULL, buffer, &temp, possiblersa)
```

This encrypts your plaintext and *claims* that the buffer you have provided is of length `possiblersa`.  That is almost certainly not true: it is very likely to be the case that `possiblersa` is much larger than `length`.

You need to delay allocating the buffer (and copying the plaintext into it) until you have found how large the ciphertext buffer needs to be.  (It will be at least as long as the plaintext, but it can be much longer.)

Comment: rsa-2048 can encrypt only 256 bytes. possiblersa = 256. temp = 14, what's wrong?

Comment: as the answer says, the API told you it needed 256 bytes of output, and you told it to go ahead and write 256 bytes into your 14 byte buffer.

Comment: @veter0 : CryptEncrypt will be writing 256 bytes of ciphertext to `buffer`.  You have allocated 14 bytes there.  You have just overflowed the buffer (by quite a lot).

Comment: ok, it's working, now I have another problem. decrypt output != original text